# Resizing images to a reference point

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a slide show where the images zooms out.

Right now, I'm using:
`$('#item').animate({width:"75%"},1000);`

When I run this, the image resizes while keeping the top and left point of the image static. How can I resize the image while keeping top and right point static? (So the image will expand toward bottom and left)

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377723/jquery-animate-expand-resize-to-the-left-rather-than-to-the-right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in a container and position it absolutely...

```
#item {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PbhWr/).

Comment: No need to position it absolutely.

Comment: @Matt Dunbar OK, what else can I do?

Comment: Fixed width container, and resize the image.  Or keep the container floating right inside another container.

Comment: @Matt Dunbar [Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/PbhWr/1/) in a fixed width container, not doing what it should.

Comment: I fixed it by floating the image to the right: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PbhWr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed width div the same size as the image originally, and set align="right".

E.g. assuming the image is 200x200:
Also, resize the image, not the container, or make another container inside this one to resize.

`<div style="width:200px;height:200px;">`

`<img src="img.jpg" align="right" />`

`</div>`

Comment: haha, its still a valid attrib.  Either way, style="align:right;".  I'm pretty sure its pretty clear what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

resizing to the left is kinda tricky but not impossible. If you have a wrapping element and the image has `float: right;` it will be pretty easy as you can see in my example. If you don't have a wrapping element you should dynamically wrap one around it and make the image float to the right. Make sure the size of the wrapping element fits the width.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Title</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

<style type="text/css">

#outerbox {
  width: 800px;
}

#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  float: right;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#box').click(function() {
      $(this).animate({width: "75%"}, 1000);
    });


  });

</script>

</head >
<body>
  <div id="outerbox">
    <div id="box">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```